# Why there's no box (for me) to answer a question?

Tags: support, reputation, answer-howto

I am relatively new in this forum but I have already 101 reputation points from other stackexchange sites. There's no absolutely no help in this subject!

Reference: The above problem regards a question at [Word for "stating the obvious?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11087/word-for-stating-the-obvious?newreg=58d7c42e1e0b41808b06eb3b1e04158f)

Comment: There is a box. Scroll down a bit.

Comment: The linked question is **protected**. It clearly states that you need "at least 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count)." Because you had already earned reputation on StackOverflow when you joined ELU you were given 100 bonus, which does not allow you to answer a protected question.

Comment: @Xanne. there is a button "Answer your Question" in this page, but any button "Answer" or input box in the page I mentioned (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11087/word-for-stating-the-obvious?newreg=58d7c42e1e0b41808b06eb3b1e04158f)

Comment: OK, @Weather. I got that. But then, how could I get 10 reputation if I can't answer at all? :)) (Vicious circle!)

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this question in here. I didn't know about "meta" site. Anyway, I have looked everywhere, including the Help section, but I found no explanation ...

Comment: Yes, by getting upvotes for answering questions that are not protected.

Comment: Users with a high enough rep can unprotect the question. Let me know when you want to post an answer, and I'll "unprotect" it.

Comment: As a general matter, Apostolos, you should know that relatively few questions on this site are "protected" in the way that the one you ask about has been. Moderators and longtime site participants normally accord such protection to questions that are especially controversial or that have repeatedly drawn frivolous or uninformed answers in the past. In contrast, most questions on EL&U are open to answering by anyone, whether that person has thousands of reputation points, 101 reputation points, or just the 1 reputation that they receive when they walk in the virtual door for the first time.

Comment: This happens often enough that we need to create a canonical dupe on Meta for these questions. The reality is that protected Qs get protected *because* they have attracted outsized attention and number of answers, so new users are more likely to see them and more likely to think they have something to contribute. They’re “easy targets”. We need an equally easy target on Meta to explain this common situation.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is found immediately below the question itself.

> protected by RegDwigнt♦ Jan 1 '13 at 13:46
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).

I can see you have not earned any reputation on this site (barring the initial 1 for joining), so you do not have the requisite 10 rep. points to answer that question. I recommend answering some other questions on this site (many are not protected) to earn the necessary points.